# mongodb substr string from behind and compare

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to use mongodb client query the data like this:

```
{ "_id" : "1231220140713" }
{ "_id" : "12320140714" },
{ "_id" : "1320140714" },
{ "_id" : "115320140714" }
```

get the result the data gte 20140714:

```
{ "_id" : "12320140714" },
{ "_id" : "1320140714" },
{ "_id" : "115320140714" }
```

the $_id last eight character strings is  date type

how can I use  `db.xxx.find()` or `db.xxx.aggregate()` deal with

Comment: what do you mean by *lgt 20140714*?

Comment: sorry ,my mean by  $gte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684970/how-to-get-last-character-from-a-string-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$substr` of aggregate does not read backwards from the string:

> If  is a negative number, $substr returns a substring that starts at the specified index and includes the rest of the string.

So that leaves JavaScript evaluation with where:

```
db.collection.find(function() { return this._id.substr(-8) >= "20140714" })
```

Not the best, but there presently is not a native operator condition that would return from the end of the string.

Comment: Do great，If i can do it via a index in order to improve the efficiency

Comment: @TheCatCanCanACan Sorry but that is a catch with both the JavaScript evaluation of `$where` and what you are basically asking in a computed match. The better process would be to store that data in a separate field, and preferably as a `Date` object as it will take less space. Then of course you can have an index on that field to improve performance. But when there is not a solid string to match "from the start" ( so even a regex does not help here ) then you cannot really get an advantage from an index.

Comment: if i use regex match the string ,so how can i do it?  the regex is [0-9]{8}$ ? how can i get the match value compare the date

Comment: @TheCatCanCanACan It would make no difference to the performance in this case. You only get a benefit from anhoring to the "start" of the string `^` and little difference for "last eight characters" compared to numeric. As I said, your real solution here is to store in a separate field.