# how to get last character from a string in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Data:

```
{code: "XXXXXXXX1", total: 400},
{code: "YYYYY2", total: 500}
{code: "ZZZZZZ3", total: 100}
{code: "AAA5", totala: 200}
```

I want to create an aggregate function to group the data above by its last character in the `code` field. `code` field is a string and can be varied in length. I only want to get its last index/number. Something like:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
 {$project: {
   last_index: {$getMyLastCharInMyCode: "$code"},
   total: 1
 }},
 {$group: {_id: "$last_index", {total: {$sum: "$total"}}}}
])
```

I searched the internet and mongodb manuals, it seems impossible. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
db.transactions.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "last_index": { $substr: [ "$code", { $subtract: [ { $strLenCP: "$code" }, 1 ] }, 1 ] }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {"$project": {
         total: 1,
         code: 1,  
         last_index: { $substr: [ "$code", { $subtract: [ {"$strLenCP": "$code"}, 1 ] }, -1 ]}
      }
 },
 {"$group": {
       "_id": "$last_index", 
       "total": {"$sum": "$total"}
     }
  }
])
```